# Remove Title attribute from an Object of Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I need to remove `Title` attribute of `templateResult` function of [select2](https://select2.org). My code is like below.

```
function resultfucntion(state) {
    //console.log(state.title);


    state.removeAttribute("title"); // this code is not working.


    if (!state.id) { return state.text;}
    var $state = $(
        '<span>' + state.text + '('+ state.text1 +')</span>'
    );
    return $state;
};

// Initialise select2
let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({        
    ajax: {
        // more code here
        processResults: function (data) {                
            var options = [];
            if (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                    var user_data = '<table> \
                        <tr> \
                        <td>Organisation</td> \
                        <td>'+text[2][1]+'</td> \
                        </tr> \
                        <tr> \
                        <td>Age</td> \
                        <td>'+ text[2][0]+'</td> \
                        </tr> \
                    </table>';          
                    options.push({ id: index, text: text[0], text1: text[1], title: user_data });
                });
            }
            return {
                results: options,
                more: false
            };
        },
    },
    templateSelection: formatState,
    templateResult: resultfucntion,
});
```

I am getting `jQuery.Deferred exception: state.removeAttribute is not a function resultfucntion` error.

[image]

I can `console.log` the object with below code.

```
      function resultfucntion(state) {

        console.log(state);

        //state.removeAttribute("title");

        if (!state.id) { return state.text;}
        var $state = $(
          '<span>' + state.text + '('+ state.text1 +')</span>'
        );
        return $state;
      };
```

I am getting output of the object like below.

```
Object { id: "1", text: "admin", text1: 0, title: "<table>                       <tr>                         <td>Organisation</td>                         <td>null</td>                       </tr>                       <tr>                         <td>Age</td>                         <td></td>                       </tr>                     </table>" }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to do like this...
` $(state).removeAttr("title");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command

```
delete state.title
```

state will be

```
{id: '1', text: 'admin', text1: 0}
```